# JDBC Driver Registration Deadlock?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jackrabbit

In one thread, a JackRabbit is being created:

```
"docs-on-startup" #32 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f730d73e800 nid=0x601d in Object.wait() [0x00007f725bffc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.getDriverClass(ConnectionFactory.java:261)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.createDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:234)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.getDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:170)
    - locked <0x000000066c71ea70> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.BundleDbPersistenceManager.getDataSource(BundleDbPersistenceManager.java:569)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.BundleDbPersistenceManager.init(BundleDbPersistenceManager.java:537)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DerbyPersistenceManager.init(DerbyPersistenceManager.java:250)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createPersistenceManager(RepositoryImpl.java:1375)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createVersionManager(RepositoryImpl.java:512)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:615)
```

and in a different thread, a driver for Postgres is being initialized using Class.forName( "org.postgresql.Driver" ):

```
"schema-task-1" #37 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f725402b000 nid=0x6021 in Object.wait() [0x00007f725baf9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.postgresql.Driver.register(Driver.java:730)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:70)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
```

None of the thread is completing its task, not sure to understand why. Is there anything wrong about the way to initialize the JDBC drivers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace, the problem seems to be that JackRabbit

1. Is loading the Derby embedded driver class,
2. which triggers the registration,
3. which triggers the classloading of `java.sql.DriverManager`,
4. which triggers `java.sql.DriverManager` to load the driver through the JDBC 4 service loader mechanism,
5. which triggers construction of a Derby embedded driver instance, which has to wait until classloading of step 1 has been completed.

As classloading is not reentrant (as far as I know), this causes everything to come to a standstill. The loading of the `DriverManager` waits for the Derby driver, which is waiting for `DriverManager`. When you then also try to load the PostgreSQL driver, it also has to wait for `DriverManager`.

This is a theory of what is causing this, and I might be wrong (because if this theory is right, I would expect it to be a more common problem). I will do some testing to see if I can reproduce this and if necessary report it to Oracle.

The real way to fix this is, is to not load drivers using `Class.forName`, but depend on the JDBC driver autoloading. However this does seem to point to a flaw in how `DriverManager` works.

A workaround could be to ensure that `java.sql.DriverManager` has already been classloaded (eg by calling one of its methods (eg `DriverManager.getLoginTimeout()`) in some initialization code before `RepositoryImpl.create` is called.

Another workaround could be to modify your JDBC driver jar(s) and remove the `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file; this will disable driver autoloading.

Comment: Thx for your input: adding DriverManager.getDrivers() before the two threads are started seems to fix the issue.